# PSTricks, node in foreground

Tags: pstricks

This is my code:

```
\psmatrix[colsep=0.45cm,rowsep=0.8cm,mnode=circle]
1,2&&1,3\\
&[mnode=none]2,3,4,5$|$1\\
1,5&&1,4
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{1,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{3,1}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{3,1}{3,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,3}{3,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{3,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{3,1}{1,3}
\endpsmatrix
```

But what I want is that the node `(2,3,4,5$|$1)` comes on the foreground (like a white box around this node). I can't draw a line to this node because there is no circle around this node (`[mnode=none]`). Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
\begin{document}

\psmatrix[colsep=0.45cm,rowsep=0.8cm,mnode=circle]
1,2 &  & 1,3\\
    & [linecolor=white]2,3,4,5$|$1\\
1,5 &  & 1,4
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{1,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{3,1}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{3,1}{3,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,3}{3,3}
%\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{3,3}
%\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{3,1}{1,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{2,2}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{2,2}{3,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{3,1}{2,2}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{2,2}{1,3}
\endpsmatrix
\rput(A){}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, if you change the node style in the middle you can get a better effect where you can better control how close the lines approach your central node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\psmatrix[colsep=0.45cm,rowsep=0.8cm,mnode=circle]
1,2 &  & 1,3\\
    & [mnode=R,linecolor=white]2,3,4,5$|$1\\
1,5 &  & 1,4
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{1,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{3,1}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{3,1}{3,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,3}{3,3}
%\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{1,1}{3,3}
%\ncline[linestyle=dashed]{3,1}{1,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed,nodesepB=0.2]{1,1}{2,2}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed,nodesepA=0.2]{2,2}{3,3}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed,nodesepB=0.2]{3,1}{2,2}
\ncline[linestyle=dashed,nodesepA=0.2]{2,2}{1,3}
\endpsmatrix
\rput(A){}
\end{document}
```

[image]